# Is this a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V = P_3$, and let $W$ = {$a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0|a_2 = 0$} be the set of cubic polynomials
with no quadratic factor. Is $W$ a subspace of $V$?

I'm certain it is but I'm unsure how to prove this. Is it enough to show that the absence of quadratic factor has no effect?

And it would be much appreciated if you could give a very brief explanation as to how to show that $\mathbb R$ (real vector space) is subspace of $\mathbb C$ (complex vector space). Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can prove $w_1,w_2\in W\implies w_1+w_2\in W$ and $w\in W\implies aw$ for any scalar $a$ then you are ready. "R is subset of C"..? Don't you mean *subspace* in stead of *subset*?

Comment: If we look at $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ as vectorspaces over field $\mathbb R$ then the scalars are elements of $\mathbb R$ and it is evident that the implications in my former comment applied on $\mathbb R$ are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Setting it out and proving the 3 properties is the issue I'm having in regards to R being a subset of C. Would I use polynomials or simply just vectors?

Comment: I mentioned $2$ properties: closed under addition and closed under scalar multiplication. That is essential for being a subspace. In this context polynomials can be looked at as vectors, so in your comment you are not posing a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity I write a polynomial $a_{n}x^{n} + \cdots + a_{0}$ as $(a_{n},\dots, a_{0})$.

If $a,b$ are scalars and $f,g \in W$, then $f = (a_{3}, a_{1},a_{0})$ and $g = (b_{3},b_{1},b_{0})$ for some $(a_{i})$ and some $(b_{i})$, so
$$
af + bg = (aa_{3} + bb_{3}, aa_{1} + bb_{1}, aa_{0}+bb_{0}) \in W,
$$
hence $W$ is a subspace of $V$.